# jq match a regex

Tags: json, jq

Let's say I have a [json](/questions/tagged/json) file, I run `cat testTab.json | jq '.action.service.spec.task| select(.container) | .container'` and it gives me

```
{
  "image": "ubuntu:latest",
  "args1": "tail",
  "args2": "-f",
  "args3": "/dev/null",
  "mounts": {
    "source": "/home/testVolume",
    "target": "/opt"
  },
  "dns_config": null
}
```

How should I edit this command the get all args (args1, args2 and args3) values ("tail" "-f" "/dev/null")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Complement your **`jq`** pipeline with the following filter:

```
jq -r 'yourfilter | to_entries 
       | map(select(.key | test("^args[0-9]+")).value) | @tsv' testTab.json
```

The output:

```
tail    -f  /dev/null
```

Though, if you would have posted your initial `testTab.json` contents - I would help to optimize your current filter.